# Route Direction in Mapview in iphone application

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I want to draw the route direction in mapview in iphone application.
And can show the reflection of walking and driving directions.

I had used this code:- [enter link description here](https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes)

It is working properly.but  it doest not having the reflection of walking and driving parameter.
I had used the url:-http://maps.google.com/maps?&output=dragdir&saddr=%@,%@&daddr=%@,%@
I had added mode=driving or mode=walking examlpe:-http://maps.google.com/maps?mode=driving&output=dragdir&saddr=%@,%@&daddr=%@,%@ 
In the code.But it doest not make any canges.Please help me how to do this

Thanks